# Global afterEach in cypress

Tags: cypress

I need a solution. I have a lot of spec files with tests and after each of them I use cy.logout command.
I want to avoid write this logout function each time and want it global.
But when I tried add this function in index.js file it was called at the beginning of each test because index.js works perfect only with beforeEach but not with afterEach.
What should I do?
Thanks

[EDIT]
I just find out that problem was provoke by my mistake in code in second test, so the only problem I have with Cypress is that I dont get any information where I made my mistake because Cypress show me that problem is afterEach hook and nothing else.

Comment: By default, cache, cookies, etc, are cleared between each tests. Are you preserving these that leaves your user logged in?

Comment: What version of Cypress are you using? I just tested using 8.7.0 (old, I know) and adding a beforeEach() and afterEach() to my `support/index.ts` file worked as global beforeEach/afterEach -- granted, I was just logging something to the console, but I saw them run at the correct time and before/after each test.

Comment: I have 9.5 Cypress version

Answer (score 0):

If you want your logout runs only once for each of your spec file, and not after each of your test within the file, you must use after instead of afterEach.

```
after(() => {
  cy.logout()
})
```

Comment: Hi. That's not what I meant. I wish to perform logout function after each test in every spec file. I just want it global to not call that function in each test. I just try to refactor my code.

Answer (score 0):

Using afterEach() or beforeEach() block in support/index.js. Refer below page to run a "global" hook

https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-before-beforeeach-after-aftereach

[image]